# cannot import name 'RollingOriginValidator'

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm writing a scoring step with Azure Machine Learning pipeline.
This is the score code:

```
import os
import pickle
import pandas as pd
from azureml.core.model import Model
import argparse
from azureml.core.run import Run, _OfflineRun
from azureml.automl.core.shared.rolling_origin_validator import RollingOriginValidator

# Called when the deployed service starts
def init():
    global model
    
    # Get the path where the deployed model can be found. 
    run = Run.get_context()
    model_path = Model.get_model_path('best_model_data')
    print(model_path)
    with open(model_path,"rb") as f:
       model = pickle.load(f)
       print("loaded")
# Handle requests to the service
def run(data):
    try:
        # Pick out the text property of the JSON request.
        # This expects a request in the form of {"text": "some text to score for sentiment"}
        prediction = predict(data)
        #Return prediction        
        return prediction
    except Exception as e:
        error = str(e)
        return error

# Predict sentiment using the model
def predict(data, include_neutral=True):
    # Tokenize text
    test_data_features=data.drop('ProposalId', 1).drop('CombinedTactics',1)
    test_data_combos=data['CombinedTactics']
    print("data")
    # Predict
    score = model.predict_proba(test_data_features)
    print("predicted")
    df=pd.DataFrame({'score':score[:, 1],'CombinedTactics':test_data_combos})
    return df
```

This is the pipeline step definition:

```
parallel_run_config = ParallelRunConfig(
    environment=myenv,
    entry_script="use_model.py",
    source_directory="./",
    output_action="append_row",
    mini_batch_size="20",
    error_threshold=1,
    compute_target=compute_target,
    process_count_per_node=2,
    node_count=2
)
parallel_step_name = "batchscoring-" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
batch_score_step = ParallelRunStep(
    name=parallel_step_name,
    inputs=[test_data.as_named_input("test_data")],
    output=output_dir,
    parallel_run_config=parallel_run_config,
    allow_reuse=True
)
```

However, I met below error:

File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/ucmopp-ws/azureml/70828787-7515-4db4-b448-a5a4b6c0c8ff/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/70828787-7515-4db4-b448-a5a4b6c0c8ff/driver/azureml_user/parallel_run/score_module.py", line 139, in call_init
self.init()
File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/ucmopp-ws/azureml/70828787-7515-4db4-b448-a5a4b6c0c8ff/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/70828787-7515-4db4-b448-a5a4b6c0c8ff/use_model.py", line 17, in init
model = pickle.load(f)
File "/azureml-envs/azureml_7e62c7905267a978aa40f8554487e9b9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/automl/runtime/featurization/**init**.py", line 8, in 
from .data_transformer import DataTransformer, TransformerAndMapper
File "/azureml-envs/azureml_7e62c7905267a978aa40f8554487e9b9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/automl/runtime/featurization/data_transformer.py", line 54, in 
from ..featurizer.transformer import (AutoMLTransformer, CategoricalFeaturizers, DateTimeFeaturesTransformer,
File "/azureml-envs/azureml_7e62c7905267a978aa40f8554487e9b9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/automl/runtime/featurizer/transformer/**init**.py", line 28, in 
from .timeseries import TimeSeriesTransformer, TimeSeriesPipelineType, NumericalizeTransformer, 
File "/azureml-envs/azureml_7e62c7905267a978aa40f8554487e9b9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/automl/runtime/featurizer/transformer/timeseries/**init**.py", line 65, in 
from azureml.automl.core.shared.rolling_origin_validator import RollingOriginValidator
ImportError: cannot import name 'RollingOriginValidator'

Does anyone have any idea about this error?

Comment: can you please run `pip freeze' in your notebook and share the output here? can you please share the automl version that you are using.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/tree/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning

Comment: azureml-automl-core==1.8.0
azureml-automl-runtime==1.8.0

Comment: Please update your Azure ML packages to the latest: `pip install azureml-sdk>=1.12.0`. That should help.